# How do I get a template from git to work on visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I'm 100% new to making apps.

Everytime I download a template (templates are social media oriented) from git (clone the repository) I follow these steps.

1. I clone in command prompt
2. I select new project from existing source and create a c# (I have tried visual basic also), I use windows application as output type on next screen (I have windows computer not sure how this option works).

However every app has the error

> Project file must include the .NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase,
>   PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list

or something along the lines of saying something about a class library.

So... I must be doing something wrong or leaving something out. Please explain the appropriate steps to take to download and run a template and develop off of it.

Comment: not really related to git.  The project is expecting references to those assemblies that it can't find.  Try looking at NuGet?

Comment: What do you mean by 'templates'? Are they valid VS solutions? Provide an example. It sounds like you're just missing some references. In you Solution Explorer, find the `Refenrences` of your current project, select `Add Reference` from the context menu and choose the assemblys from the error message.